# Design choice regarding manipulation of main loop from treegraph

Tags: c++, tree, encapsulation

I'm creating a simple game for programming practice on bigger projects and am currently stuck at a crossroad.

The game uses a treegraph structure to store all the entities of the game, all extending from the base class called TreeNode that implements some basic functions such as attaching and detaching children from themselves as well as their position in the 2D world.

My problem is that I want to create a sort of "Action Node" that upon collision with the player allows various events to take place, such as changing the song being played, trigger a pause with subsequent dialogue, ending the stage etc etc.

**My question is, how would i implement this in a decent way that doesn't beat my efforts of code isolation to a bloody pulp? I was thinking of making a new class with a std::function member that i can program to do what i want it to do, but that way would mean completely breaking code encapsulation by handing it a reference to my master class that contains ALL data in the entire game.**

Collision is currently implemented something like this:

```
std::vector<std::pair<&TreeNode, &TreeNode>> vCollision;
MasterNode.checkCollision(vCollision);
```

checkCollision gets called with a reference to the vector, invokes collision checks recursively on the rest of the graph and fills the vector with pairs of different entities that have collided. (this is in the update loop.)
**I also need to figure out a  way to be able to call said std::function from this list since pointers to the base class wont have access to members of derived classes.**

Answer (score 0):

A tree structure is a container that can be used with different data types.  Because of this, it is a good candidate for *templates*.

Since you have your tree working, factor out the data type to a template parameter.
For example, given a node:

```
struct Tree_Node
{
  struct Tree_Node * left_subtree;
  struct Tree_Node * right_subtree;
  Some_Data_Type     node_data;
};
```

You can factor out the data type using templates:

```
template <class Node_Data_Type>
struct Tree_Node
{
  struct Tree_Node * left_subtree;
  struct Tree_Node * right_subtree;
  Node_Data_Type     node_data;
};
```

You would declare a tree node as:

```
struct Player_Data;
Struct Moves_Data;
struct Tree_Node<Player_Data>; // For a tree of Player_Data
struct Tree_Node<Moves_Data>; // For a tree of Moves_Data
```

An alternative is to use inheritance for the node data.

```
struct Node_Data_Base
{
   virtual bool is_equal(Node_Data_Base * p_node) const = 0;
   virtual bool is_less(Node_Data_Base * p_node) const = 0;
   bool operator==(Node_Data_Base * p_node) const
   {
     return is_equal(p_node);  // Dispatch to child.
   }
   bool operator<(Node_Data_Base * p_node) const
   {
     return is_less(p_node); // dispatch to child.
   }
};

struct Tree_Node_Inheritance
{
  struct Tree_Node * left_subtree;
  struct Tree_Node * right_subtree;
  Node_Data_Base *   p_data;
};
```

Also, review the `std::map` data type.

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts but it didn't really answer my questions. I'll highlight my questions in the original post and apologize if I have been unclear. :/

Comment: The problem is that you hard-coded data in the `TreeNode` class.  So, if you want any of the items to invoke an action or two, you will need to modify the `TreeNode` class.  You can add either a pointer to a function, or a pointer to a Function Class (something that overloads `operator()`).